# How to determine the length of a particular array

Tags: excel, vba

Determine the length of a particular array.  Have tried several variations of Value but no joy.

Within a macro I've tried:

```
Range("BB4").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("BB5").Select
Range("BB5:BB4804").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

I want the UBound of BB which can vary and not paste in a particular value such as BB4804.

The shown code works but if the length of the array (BB column) is less or exactly 4804.  But it increases, the longer cells are dropped.

Comment: Can you show us your full code, where you are capturing the BB column as an array? By the column, do you mean only non-empty values? More description is needed.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need the last row of `BB` column. To achieve that you can use `.End(xlUp).Row`. In your code it would be like this:

```
LastRow = Range("BB" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("BB5:BB" & LastRow).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

> **Note**: This will not work in case the column is completely empty.

Hope this helps.

Comment: To test I ran that below on an excel with column A having 4804 rows

Sub test()
Dim LastRow
'
   LastRow = Range("A1:A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
   Debug.Print LastRow

End Sub

It prints 1

Comment: @RalphNelson Yes, there was a typo in the code. Try now, I've tested it and it should work.

Comment: Yes, that now picks up the number of the last row.   Thanks!